# Python/Regex Partial String Replacement

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Edited to clarify what I tried and what my goals are.

My goal is to take a list, and for each element in the list replace any character immediately following a pipe (if such character exists) with "X".

For example:

`[A|1,B|C,D|9]` would become `[A|X,B|X,D|X]`

From looking online I think it would be some sort of regex, but I am not sure how to get specifically the one character following.

I have tried

```
re.sub('|*?', "X", listname)
```

but get a "dangling metacharacter" error before even starting. I want to say: "Take any single character following a | and change that character to an X.

I have also tried:

```
re.sub('\|(.)', "X", listname)
```

but get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Some more context on what I am looking for to clarify comments...

In my specific code a | will always be followed by something. I only care about the first character of that "something". So [A|124,B|s] would need to yield [A|X24,B|X]

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far! and tell about your problems if you want to get a desire answer! because SO is not a *do it for me* website!

Comment: Off you go: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Do you want to replace a following character or following word, ie does `A|12` become `A|X2` or `A|X`?

Comment: @hwnd I would want nothing to match. That said, for my specific code I never encounter that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A preceding-match clause is more correct but may be harder to understand.

You might find it easier to just match the `|` and substitute it back again:

```
import re

data = ['A|1', 'B|C', 'D|9']
data = [re.sub("\|.", "|X", d) for d in data]

# data = ['A|X', 'B|X', 'D|X']
```

Comment: Yes much easier to understand for someone that does not understand regular expressions =)

Comment: Yes very easy for a python noob like myself to grasp!

Answer (score 4):

> I want to say: "Take any single character following a `|` and change that character to an **X**.

You can do this using a list comprehension and the following regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> lst = ['A|1', 'B|C', 'D|9', 'E|124', 'F|s']
>>> [re.sub(r'(?<=\|).', 'X', x) for x in lst]
['A|X', 'B|X', 'D|X', 'E|X24', 'F|X']
```

[`(?<= ... )`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is a zero-width assertion which does not "consume" any characters on the string, but only asserts that what immediately precedes the current position in the string is `|`.